# Limit the number of times a key can be pressed in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a simple dice game with pygame and I am trying to only allow for the spacebar key to be pressed 5 times maximum, until the game is finished and scores are presented. This is a snippet of my code:

```
...

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False

    for i in range (5): #number of wanted rounds
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                dice1.roll = True #rolls dice
                dice2.roll = True #rolls dice
                player_one.new_score(dice1_set) #calculates P1 new score
                player_two.new_score(dice2_set) #calculates P2 new score
```

However, this still allows the spacebar key to be pressed any number of times and the die will still roll whenever it is pressed. How do I make sure that after the spacebar key has been pressed five times, pressing it again will not make the die start rolling again and instead I can start printing the scores etc?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of a counter or a flag to know when to stop rolling dice or generally trigger or stop some action. Something like this works:

```
if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pg.K_SPACE and SPACE_COUNTER < 5:
        SPACE_COUNTER +=1

    else:
        print("PUT YOUR CODE FOR SCORE RESET")

    if event.key == pg.K_RETURN and SPACE_COUNTER >= 5:
        SPACE_COUNTER = 0
```

I assume all this happens inside of your `main_loop` so `SPACE_COUNTER` is global variable and it is defined as `SPACE_COUNTER = 0` outside of the loop.
Last line is for restarting the variable, when you hit Enter and the counter is already on 5 it will reset it to 0
You could also make separate function just for counting. Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad I could help. Since it solved your issue, please consider accepting the solution, thank you.